Is there a way to add manual time to a work diary via the new Upwork GraphQL API?
From what I can make out of the GraphQL and earlier APIs there is no method to add manual time to an activity for the freelancer.
I've been reading the new current API documentation here:
https://www.upwork.com/developer/documentation/graphql/api/docs/index.html
For context, this would be needed as a method of tracking time on hourly contracts, on currently unsupported environments such as iOS. I understand why they are reluctant to support time with guaranteed payment via the API, but they could allow more accurate tracking as manual time.
This question is just focussed on if there is a method, possibly undocumented, of adding manual time via the currently published GraphQL API.
